# Get number of objects of csv

Tags: python

How would I get the number of 'lines' in a CSV file. Here is what I have tried:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(filepath), delimiter='|')
print len(reader)
AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

Comment: DictReader does not return a dict but a reader.  You then have to traverse the result set somehow.  EDIT: see @adrCoder answer below for such an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `sum` using a generator expression the len of each row without reading each all into a list if you just want to do is  count the total elements:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filepath), delimiter='|')

print(sum(len(row) for row in reader))
```

Or just open and split:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    print(sum(len(line.split("|")) for line in f))
```

If you want the actual line count:

```
 with open(filepath) as f:
        print(sum(1 for _ in f))
```

Comment: All correct, but note the OP is using [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) that may 1) have fewer records since it automatically handles the header and 2) fewer fields since extras are placed in another separate value.

Comment: Your first method works more or less. Just replace `csv.reader` with `csv.DictReader` and then test that each field is in `reader.fieldnames` before counting it as part of the length.

Comment: @dawg.  wouldn't  `+  len(reader.fieldnames)` be the same as summing the `rows` over  csv.reader. I think the OP actually wants the total line count so the last example is probably most relevant

Comment: *the last example is probably most relevant*: Off by 1 at a minimum tho since the header is counted with `sum(1 for _ in f)` and not in the case of `csv.DictReader `  The method I am suggesting would be something like `sum(any(set(row.keys()) & set(reader.fieldnames))` since it is certainly possible that some rows contain no data given certain header fieldnames...

Comment: True, but does not handle potentially rows with no matching value to the keys given DictReader (rare, but possible...).

Comment: @dawg. Yes. I am not sure exactly what the OP wants to include. I am not convinced DictReader is necessarily what the OP wants .

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
rows = list(reader)
totalrows = len(rows)
```